# Jquery get text() from structure .text(value)

Tags: jquery

It's probably a very noob question, but still I don't get it. While working with jquery file upload plugin, I want to get file name and covert it to text. There is a small example of code which converts it to text and appends later to table (original code from plugin):

```
$('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
```

I want to get file.name to var like a text (or string). I've tried this way:

```
var filename = file.name.text();
```

But this is not working. What's the other possible ways to get this done?

Comment: `var filename = file.name;`

Comment: isn't `file.name` already a variable containing a string ?

Comment: if I will put file.name in alert it will return Obj.

Comment: Use `console.log(variable);` instead of alert. If what you put in `alert` is a javascript object it will output Obj and you will not be able to see its contents.

Answer (score 0):

`file.name` points to the property `name` of your uploaded `file`, so it's already a string.
You can use it as a variable or you can asign its value to a new variable like `var filename = file.name`.

The method `text()` of jQuery is used to get, in text format, the content of an element. For example, if you have following html:

```
<body>
    <p id="myP">This is my text</p>
</body>
```

You can use `$('#myP').text()` to get `"This is my text"`.

The method `text()` also allows you to change the text of an element if you includes a parameter inside. For example `$('#myP').text("This is my new text")` will change your html code to:

```
<body>
    <p id="myP">This is my new text</p>
</body>
```